# I added cron from cpanel in codeigniter that's not working

Tags: codeigniter-2, cpanel

I tried to add cron job from cpanel for below url
for every minutes and added command as
/usr/local/lib/php /home/bestofwo/public_html/index.php pilots/rouwadvertenties RouwmediaAPI ImportTest

similar as below
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/{cpanel_user}/public_html/index.php controller function

but cron is not running...how can i check from cpanel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redirect your cron output in log file and check if there is any error with your cron.

```
 /usr/bin/php -q  /home/{cpanel_user}/public_html/index.php >> cron.log
```